# I'd like to create a progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show the progress for my `todo list`

Here is the code for my progress bar

```
<!-- todo list -->
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-hovered mb20 todo" id="todoApp">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span>Todo List</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled todo-list">

            </ul>

            <!-- Add todo input -->
            <form id="input-todo" class="input-todo">
                    <input placeholder="Write some todo task here..." type="text">
            </form>
        </div> <!-- #end panel-body -->
        <div class="panel-footer todo-foot clearfix" id="todo-filters">
            <div class="left">
                    <button class="btn btn-pink btn-xs right toggle-all">Toggle All</button>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                    <span class="remaining btn btn-xs btn-default">left</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-pink btn-xs clear-completed">Clear Completed</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- #end panel -->
```

Here is my `todo` code

```
    jQuery(function(){{
function addTodoHtml(todo,index)
{
var html='<li data-index="'+index+'" class="'+(todo.completed?"completed":"")+'">
    <div class="ui-checkbox ui-checkbox-pink">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="toggle" '+ todo.completed?"checked":"")+'/>
                        <span></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="todo-title"><p>'+todo.title+'</p><form class="todo-edit">
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <span class="destroy ion ion-close right"></span>
                </li>';$todoApp.find(".todo-list").append(html)}function reArrangeIndex(){$todoApp.find(".todo-list > li").each(function(i){$(this).data("index",i)})}function removeTodo(){var todo=$(this).parent(),isCompleted=todo.find("input.toggle")[0].checked,todoNo=todo.index();todo.remove(),scope.remainingCount-=isCompleted?0:1,todos.splice(todoNo,1),todoStore.put(todos),reArrangeIndex(),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .remaining").html(scope.remainingCount+" left")}function toggleCompleted(){var todo=$(this).parents("li"),todoNo=todo.index(),isCompleted=this.checked;console.log(todoNo),scope.remainingCount+=isCompleted?-1:1,todos[todoNo].completed=isCompleted,todoStore.put(todos),todo.toggleClass("completed"),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .remaining").html(scope.remainingCount+" left")}function markAll(){var $todos=$todoApp.find(".todo-list li"),rc=0,allChecked=!1;todos.forEach(function(todo){todo.completed||++rc}),0==rc&&(allChecked=!0),todos.forEach(function(todo){todo.completed=!allChecked}),scope.remainingCount=allChecked?0:todos.length,todoStore.put(todos),$todos.each(function(i,todo){var $t=$(todo),input=$t.find("input.toggle")[0];allChecked?($(todo).removeClass("completed"),input.checked=!1):($(todo).addClass("completed"),input.checked=!0)}),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .remaining").html(scope.remainingCount+" left")}function addTodo(e){e.preventDefault();var todoTitle=$(this).children().val();scope.newTodo=todoTitle;var newTodo={title:scope.newTodo.trim(),completed:!1};0!=scope.newTodo.length&&(todos.push(newTodo),todoStore.put(todos),scope.newTodo="",scope.remainingCount++,addTodoHtml(newTodo,todos.length-1),setTimeout(function(){$todoApp.find(".todo-list li:last-child .destroy").on("click touchstart",removeTodo)}),$(this).children().val(""),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .remaining").html(scope.remainingCount+" left"))}function doneEditing(todo,todoTitle,isCompleted,todoNo){todo.removeClass("editing"),todoTitle=todoTitle.trim(),todos[todoNo].title=todoTitle,todoTitle||scope.removeTodo(todo,isCompleted,todoNo),todoStore.put(todos),todo.find(".todo-title p").html(todoTitle)}function editTodo(){var todo=$(this).parent(),todoNo=todo.index(),stodo=todos[todoNo],isCompleted=stodo.completed;todo.addClass("editing"),$(this).find("input").val(stodo.title.trim()),$todoApp.find(".todo-title .todo-edit").on("submit",function(e){e.preventDefault();var todoTitle=$(this).find("input").val();doneEditing(todo,todoTitle,isCompleted,todoNo)})}function clearCompleted(){todos=todos.filter(function(val){return!val.completed}),todoStore.put(todos);var $todos=$todoApp.find(".todo-list li").filter(function(i,todo){return $(todo).hasClass("completed")});$todos.remove()}var $todoApp=$("#todoApp"),STORAGE_ID="_todo-task",todoStore={todos:[],get:function(){return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID))},put:function(todos){localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID,JSON.stringify(todos))
}},demoTodos=[{title:"Eat healthy, Eat fresh",completed:!1},{title:"Donate some money",completed:!0},{title:"Wake up at 5:00 A.M",completed:!1},{title:"Hangout with friends at 12:00",completed:!1},{title:"Another todo on the list. Add as many you want.",completed:!1},{title:"The last but not the least.",completed:!0}],todos=todoStore.get()||demoTodos,scope={newTodo:"",remainingCount:todos.filter(function(val){return 0==val.completed}).length,editedTodo:null,originalTodo:"",statusFilter:null,edited:!1,todoshow:"all",allChecked:!1};todos.forEach(function(todo,index){addTodoHtml(todo,index)}),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .remaining").html(scope.remainingCount+" left"),$todoApp.find(".destroy").on("click touchstart",removeTodo),$todoApp.find("li input.toggle").on("change",toggleCompleted),$todoApp.find("#input-todo").on("submit",addTodo),$todoApp.find(".todo-title").on("dblclick",editTodo),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .toggle-all").on("click touchstart",markAll),$todoApp.find(".todo-foot .clear-completed").on("click touchstart",clearCompleted)}function
    _init(){initSparklines(),initC3Chart(),initEasyPieChart(),initRating(),TodoApp()}var $dash=$(".page-dashboard");_init()});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the problem you're facing exactly?

Comment: i want my progress bar to use the when you add, delete, and check on todo list activity